# Processing can't find a callback function from a save dialog

Tags: java, file, processing

For whatever reason, Processing does not seem to find the callback function after I select a file using `selectOutput()`. Here is the part of my code where I am trying to save a file:

```
void saveProjectDialog() { // Shows a save file dialog
  JSONObject header = new JSONObject();
  header.setString("name", proj_name);

  selectOutput(getLang("SaveDialog"), "saveProject");
}

void saveProject(File selection) { // Save file dialog callback
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Save dialog was closed, canceled save.");
  } else {
    println("Saving to " + selection.getAbsolutePath());
    saveJSONArray(project, selection.getAbsolutePath());
    println("Construction saved!");
  }
}
```

When I select the path, this is printed out to the console:

```
saveProject() could not be found
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What version of Processing are you using ? I've just tested with 3.2.3 and it works as expected

Comment: What are the `getLang()` function and `proj_name` and `project` variables? Can you please hardcode them and post a [mcve]?

Comment: `getLang()` is a function that gets a string from a JSON file. `proj_name` is a String that I use for a project name. `project` is a JSONArray that holds objects - shapes (points as for now). This is purely the data that I want to save, but I was talking about a problem with the `selectOutput()`. I was using Processing 3.2.3, I will be updating to 3.2.4 today. You can see the whole code on my GitHub, repo `liquid600pgm/geometroid-pi`

Answer (score 0):

Using this test sketch worked:

```
JSONArray project = new JSONArray();

String proj_name = "test";

void saveProjectDialog() { // Shows a save file dialog
  JSONObject header = new JSONObject();
  header.setString("name", proj_name);

  selectOutput(getLang("SaveDialog"), "saveProject");
}

void saveProject(File selection) { // Save file dialog callback
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Save dialog was closed, canceled save.");
  } else {
    println("Saving to " + selection.getAbsolutePath());
    saveJSONArray(project, selection.getAbsolutePath());
    println("Construction saved!");
  }
}

void setup(){
  saveProjectDialog();
}

String getLang(String s){
  return s;
}
```

Double check the values `proj_name` and `getLang()` result.